# plugin not showing in admin panel

Tags: wordpress

i've installed a plugin via wp cli and set it active but when trying to call it's shortcode it doesn't work. when i logged into the admin area it's not listed. the permissions are set to 755 as it appears all the others are. i have the plugin on my test system working fine so i copied the value of active_plugins in wp_options but on refreshing the plugins page in admin, it always resets the values back. it's a single standalone site. any ideas on how i can get the plugin to appear in the list and/or stop the value of acitve_plugins from resetting?

Comment: Have you tried uploading via the normal method, and seeing if that works?

Comment: yeah i tried that first but i got an error telling me wp-content cant be found. a colleague told me we've gotta use the cli method on that server :(

Comment: :S What? So do you access /wp-admin/ at all or are you not able to? doesn't sound like a great server to be running Wordpress on at all.

Comment: yeah i can access wp-admin and do all the normal sorta stuff just not plugins. im new here and the guy who could explain the setup to me better is away. ive seen this issue reported before but it's always seems to be with a multi-site set up

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of anything like this before. To me, it would suggest there are serious problems with your Wordpress installation, and I'd recommend compeltely starting from scratch, it sounds like something may be corrupt in your database.